# In Linux kernel how to identify the opened file when we can get "struct file"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

In linux kernel how to identify the opened files? When we can get the information about inodes or (struct file) or dentry? Which structure can help us to identify the opened files which is the same opened file? Can you tell me details?

Answer (score 3):

One physical file has only one `struct inode` at any one time.

On most filesystems the inode number will stay the same even when the `struct inode` is deallocated and read back later, so you can identify by that (plus device number), but there are exceptions. But it is always ensured at least that only one file on a device will have a particular inode number at any given time (this is used to check two open filehandles point to the same file in userland where you don't have access to `struct inode`—in kernel comparing the pointers will be easier).

One file may have more `struct file` associated with it, one for each file handle in some process and it may have more than one `struct dentry` associated with it, one per hardlink.

It comes from this that there is only one `struct dentry` for any path in the filesystem. The path may however look differently from different process point of view (think chroots and namespaces). It can be reconstructed by walking up the chain of dentries and inodes (each dentry has parent inode and each inode knows dentries currently associated with it), but you have to be careful to avoid the dentries not visible to current process.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.I'm sorry for my questions.What i want to identify is file handle. When I can get all file handles in Linux kernel, but i don't know how to identify whether they are the same ones. And meantime file handle is a pointer. Would you help me?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have got it. In linux kernel I have to count the number of files the system has visited and i can get struct dentry and inode. On this condition I can log the filesystem path in the syslog, then make statistics? Because pointers will be changed when file handles changes(so inode is not used). Am i right? and where can i get the filesystem path? Looking forward you.

Comment: @user824675: You can get the path using `d_path` function, but it's useless, because a file may have many paths (many more than hardlinks, because a filesystem may be mounted multiple times and bind-mounted a couple more). You have to log the device and inode numbers from the `struct inode` as I explained above.